# APC serialization slow?

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, apc

Example:

```
$arr = array();

for($i = 5; $i < 300000; $i++)
    $arr[$i] = 'foo';

apc_store('data', $arr);
```

It takes like 15 seconds. To get the data it takes around 0.7s.

But if I serialize the data with php and store it like that with `apc_store('data', serialize($arr));` it takes only 1 second.

To get the serialized data and then unserialize it, it takes a little more than 0.6s

Why is APC so slow?

Comment: `apc_store()` triggers the `__sleep()` function, right?  If that's true, then the [function is run prior to serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.magic-functions.php).  Maybe that cuts down on the efficiency.  It also sounds like `apc_store()` overwrites existing entries... granted I'm still learning PHP so I could be way off.

Comment: @MikeDtrick: APC doesn't use serialization. It just copies entire `zval` structure (on C level).

Comment: @Crozin Wait, what?  Is this in regards to `apc_store()` triggering `__sleep()`?  Is that incorrect?

Comment: @MikeDtrick Sorry, my mistake. APC *triggers* `__sleep()` method.

Comment: @Alex Could you check your code on different platform? On my PC (i3, Windows 7 x64 - not the best env. for APC) version without serialization works ~30% **faster**.

Comment: APC does serialize whatever userdata it stores: in the case of objects, this triggers __sleep().... pre-serializing before calling apc_store will create a string to be stored; and APC will reserialize it. Using the igbinary extension can improve performance because it's a more efficient serialization method

Answer (score 2):

apc_sma_info() provides one interesting information which, maybe, could explain why happens.

Executing apc_store() with a non-serialized data produces to me, in **block_lists** index the following values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [size] => 608
            [offset] => 33152
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [size] => 5589032
            [offset] => 11211992
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [size] => 2175976
            [offset] => 31378408
        )
)
```

While serializing them manually produces:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [size] => 11178232
                [offset] => 33760
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [size] => 1210040
                [offset] => 16801024
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [size] => 15542104
                [offset] => 18012280
            )
    )
```

It's curious, but seems that with a manual serialization, APC splits the first and last pieces of data in a larger blocks, doing a better disposition of content.

Doesn't seem to be something trivial because I ran this test a couple times and I got similar results everytime.